# exception on save request : parse cloud

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, parse-platform

I am facing exception "Invalid response from server" while in simple code. I installed package through nuget.

```
MainPage()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 ParseClient.Initialize("*****", "******");
 AddData();
}
 async void AddData()
 {
 ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
 gameScore["score"] = 1337;
 gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott";
 await gameScore.SaveAsync(); /// Exception here
 }
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, this happens due to internet connection! Please check that is IE is opening in your simmulator; it its not then this is your solution(use some other internet connection).